# Compilation error: invalid access of mutable storage in an isolated function

Tags: ballerina

Why isolated function `sum1` gives a compilation error but isolated function `sum2` doesn't?

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    io:println(sum1([1,2,3,4], [0,1]));
    io:println(sum2([1,2,3,4], [0,1]));
}

isolated function sum1(int[] numbers, int[] indexes) returns int {
    return indexes.reduce(isolated function (int accu, int index) returns int {
        // ERROR invalid access of mutable storage in an 'isolated' function
        return accu + numbers[index];
    }, 0);
}

isolated function sum2(int[] numbers, int[] indexes) returns int {
    int accu = 0;
    foreach int index in indexes {
        // but here we can access
        accu += numbers[index];
    }
    return accu;
}
```

```
$ bal build issue.bal 
Compiling source
    issue.bal
ERROR [issue.bal:(11:23,11:30)] invalid access of mutable storage in an 'isolated' function
error: compilation contains errors
```

I'm using:

```
$ bal version
Ballerina 2201.1.0 (Swan Lake Update 1)
Language specification 2022R2
Update Tool 1.3.9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because additional rules are applicable in an `isolated` anonymous function. An `isolated` anonymous function (such as that which is passed as an argument to the `reduce` function) can refer to a captured variable (a parameter or a local variable declared outside the anonymous function, such as `numbers` in the example) only if it is both `final` (explicitly or implicitly) and has a static type that is a subtype of `readonly|isolated object {}`.

There is an [open spec issue](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/issues/602) to look into how something like this can be allowed in the future.

Comment: Sad to see the issue :( Unfortunately this is yet another "smallish" issue that reduces the usefulness of anonymous functions and closures in "real" code (that needs to be isolated). Hope to see the issue fixed at some day :)